# $\prod_{k=0}^{\infty} \cos(x \cdot 2^{-k}).$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, infinite-product

Please, can you help me to find the limit of the example[image]

where n goes to infinity ?

Comment: Please set the notation more properly

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706749/find-the-product

Answer (score 0):

Hint: write cos(x/2) = sinx/(2sin(x/2)), and cos(x/4) = sin(x/2)/(2sin(x/4)), etc...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $\frac{\sin x}{x}$.

See to this question's #1 answer: [$\prod_{k=3}^{\infty} 1 - \tan( \pi/2^k)^4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10186/finding-a-closed-form-for-an-infinite-product)

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information (since you received good answers for the limit), the product from $i=1$ to $i=n$ of $\cos \left(2^{-i} x\right)$ has a closed form which is $$2^{-n} \sin (x) \csc \left(2^{-n} x\right)$$